# Substitute % in makefile globally?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make, substitution

I'm having a set of projects

```
PROJECTS = project1 project2
```

Now I'd like to get a list of wars to build, they are project1/target/project1.war.
I can't find a rule to generate the war names from the project names. GNU make seems to expand % only once, so if I do

```
WARS = $(PROJECTS:%=%/target/%.war)
```

I get `project1/target/%.war project2/target/%.war`

Is there any way to get make to to a "global" replace?

(Please don't tell me to use another build system, this is not an option for me)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
WARS = $(foreach name,$(PROJECTS),$(name)/target/$(name).war)
```